# Image path containing space not being found

Tags: iis-7, filenames

Theres an image on the homepage of my site with the path:

```
/Images/Advert/advert one.jpg
```

This has been displaying on the page in the last week, but now the image cannot be found. I've checked the location, and its not been removed. I simply changed the path to:

```
/Images/Advert/advert-one.jpg
```

And now the image is found! Why does having a space in the path prevent the browser from finding it?

There are people other than myself who have access to the server, so its possible they have changed a setting, although they believe they haven't, and furthermore I didn't realise such a setting would exist?

Answer (score 0):

URLs cant contain a space. Try replacing the space with %20, e.g. `/Images/Advert/advert%20one.jpg`

Comment: I tried this, and it still didn't work. I think its not true that URLs cannot contain a space, as it was working last week.

Comment: Have a look at [http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_urlencode.asp](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_urlencode.asp), one suggestion is to try and use a + instead of a space.

Comment: I've tried encoding the URL and it doesn't work. My issue is that the site has been operational for over a year now, with many filenames containing spaces. It's only during this past week that they have stopped working